# Sort output of grep by file size? (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to grep for a certain string, in a certain directory. Then I want to sort the files by size (number of bytes would be fine). The files are .php files, though I don't think other non-php files would have the string I'm looking for. How do I do this?

I got the grep part:

`grep -rl "foostring" ~/myfolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in order of decreasing size:

```
matching_files_by_size() {
    local matching_paths path
    mapfile -d '' -t matching_paths < <(grep --files-with-matches --null --recursive "$@")
    for path in "${matching_paths[@]}"
    do
        printf '%s\t%q\n' "$(du --bytes -- "$path" | cut --fields=1)" "$path"
    done | sort --key=1 --numeric-sort --reverse | cut --fields=2
}
```

Supports any paths by shell-escaping the output.

Prerequisites: GNU `sed`/`grep`, Bash 4.